# git log macOS problems

Tags: git, macos, git-log

I have git installed and am able to run all the basic commands, except for git log.

When I try to run git log this is what I get :

```
⑂master  git log

$(brew--prefix)/share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight |     LESS=${LESS:-FRX} $(git var GIT_PAGER): brew--prefix: command not found
$(brew--prefix)/share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight |     LESS=${LESS:-FRX} $(git var GIT_PAGER): /share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone faced this issue? I'd appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: how do you try to run git log? do you show us the error or the command?

Comment: It is `brew --prefix` with a space in between.

Comment: The error I posted is returned from me as an error when I run 'git log'.  Where do I add the space between brew --prefix?

Comment: Where are you running this? What is the output of `type git`?

Comment: You configured something (I'm not sure what) to use `$(brew--prefix)/share/...)`. When you did that configuration you misspelled it (leaving out the space). Re-do whatever configuration you did at that point, and this time, spell it with the space.

Comment: I checkout my config file, it already has the space between brew and --prefix, like you suggested.

Comment: Im running this in a project directory (command line). And the output to type git is : git is hashed (/usr/local/bin/git)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I figured it out. So my .bashrc file uses another .sh file for configuration, and the space was missing in that other .sh file. So adding a space in there fixed it for me. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Mark Setchell :

Adding a space in between brew --prefix fixes the problem.